# how to parse timestamp in R?

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

I am using lubridate to parse a timestamp to POSIXlt.

```
user   time
____   ____
 1      2017-09-01 00:01:01
 1      2017-09-01 00:01:20
 1      2017-09-01 00:03:01
library(lubridate)
data[, time:=parse_date_time2(time,orders="YmdHMS",tz="NA")]
```

But this resulted in

**Warning message:
In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(.mklt(.Call("parse_dt", x, orders, FALSE,  :
  unknown timezone 'NA'**
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Datetimes always have a time zone. And I can tell you it's not "NA".

Comment: Are you sure that your format `"YmdHMS"` is correct for the input?

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse simply without `tz`

```
> ts <- '2017-09-01 00:01:01'
> lubridate::parse_date_time2(ts,orders="YmdHMS")
[1] "2017-09-01 00:01:01 UTC"
```

Similar to input code:

```
data[, time:=parse_date_time2(time,orders="YmdHMS")]
```